# Union of tuples to corresponding types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a type with

```
type Union = [1, "one"] | [1, "first"] | [2, "two"]

type GetTuple<T, U> = Extract<T, [U, ...unknown[]]>;

type ObjectFromUnion<T extends Union[0] = Union[0]> = {
  number: T
  word: ??
}
```

I want to use `ObjectFromUnion` type as React component props type, so I wont need pass a generic type itself, it should infer based on `number` and `word` props values.

So, for example, this is what expected for the compiler to do:

```
<Component number={1} word=/* "one" | "first" */ /> 
<Component number={2} word=/* "two" */ /> 
<Component word="one" number=/* {1} */ /> 
<Component word="first" number=/* {1} */ /> 
<Component word="two" number=/* {2} */ />
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigbQIwBooDkKEBAulAD5Z6EBmCATgM7BmVYBM+BwA7kmQDcAWABQY0JCgBxCMAAqAVzAAbCAB55+GAD50UAKIAPYAwCGAY2Cb8mGPgB0TxXADWcJLziZSpHSPFRSWglVQgAeVoAMUYWfVkFZTV1eGQ4fGx-KAB6bOp8ACJiAvIqHEK+JBKJcBCkiNoAZQgLFAATeLlQ5NSUfA4s3M4K-mqg2qhuhvkAC0YOjASplMQ+qABmQby4CAA3CAYxIA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Thanks for your help! I've updated a question to correspond to my needs more, I'd appreciate if you take a look.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/N95l9N) work?

Comment: Or [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCpgE8wk4BVAO2AhbgF44BtARgA0BDknwBdOAB8+QgpmBQAzjAnS+AJmH4YAdwgSK1SnQZwA8gCMAVkgwAxHCFbsWAHgAqcJAA8YSFgATJWY2Dm5Q1wA+bi9ffyCQrwB+OABvKjgsuBYAVxBLJCgALjgPXgAGcSNsuH0oQNLy-mqqAF84UpYkADcioyoqNA4VOABhXEhulngeT28-AODI8J4XDiiACjAcMCVSq1sHJ3X3DyiASm4YjMpaohhcqE48gBtXozbBymGWUaIgkUIpsrlwYptMtk3FFvrVam4JuBRDMcvlClAuGl+B16oEuAAiUT4uAAehhdzhWQRk2R8DyBSKmI0OOgePxeggxLJkMp1KR03guIJRNRDIxWI63IpvMRUwCgtZBIUyhgxPp6Mx2NJ5MpVNltLqivZ+jVaMZaWZ2p5cL5cpRQuNnNFGol2tJJIWDAwSEC3igOCg1rcUouQA)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using mapped types.

```
type Union = [1, "one"] | [1, "first"] | [2, "two"];
type UType = {[K in Union as K[0]]: K[1]};

function Component<I extends keyof UType>(props: {number: I; word: UType[I]}) {
    return <div>{props.number}: {props.word}</div>
}
```

Here is a [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigbQIwBooBEKEBAulAD5Z6EBmCATgM7BmVYBM%20BwA7kmQDcAWABQoSLAAq4aBgDemANJQEqeMlQBDJlCWYADKVIAuPTlIBfEaLG0ArnADGwTVADCAHgCSUCAA9gCDgAE10AawgQJFppWQA%20AAowBiQwJjN5OHsAWwAjCAYzb0EofgYQsxgZSExvKwBKKHkxKDaoBghgewZUTxCEADd4%20RS0pgA6bPzCy0yx9InykMtPAHoB4bFLMTFPeNb2z3coaYKGNHlsSzKkCrQCemZWNYPRdqhj09zzy%20vb%205EOAkV6HNpfM6FS4cG7LB58ASg95HE6Qi5XWF3ELw-gEJEfL5wni4tr4lEA7EERwAWjUIWCrnoEBC1MGWgANgRSW91m8gA).

Once you put in the number, you get narrowing and code completion on the word.

Comment: and if you update to:

`type UType = {[K in Union as `${K[0]}`]: K[1]};`

you will get code completion on the number as well (but, as string)